# Graphical glitches when adding cells and scrolling with UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I am using a UITableView to display the results of a series of calculations. When the user hits 'calculate', I add the latest result to the screen. When I add a new cell, the `UITableViewCell` object is added to an array (which is indexed by `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`), and then I use the following code to add this new row to what is displayed on the screen:

```
[thisView beginUpdates];
[thisView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[thisView endUpdates];
```

This results in the new cell being displayed. However, I then want to immediately scroll the screen down so that the new cell is the lowermost cell on-screen. I use the following code:

```
[thisView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:newIndexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
```

This **almost** works great. However, the first time a cell is added and scrolled to, it appears onscreen only briefly before vanishing. The view scrolls down to the correct place, but the cell is not there. Scrolling the view by hand until this invisible new cell's position is offscreen, then back again, causes the cell to appear - after which it behaves normally. This only happens the first time a cell is added; subsequent cells don't have this problem. It also happens regardless of the combination of `scrollToRowAtIndexPath` and `insertRowsAtIndexPath` animation settings.

**EDIT:**
*I've now started inserting cells at the second-to-last position of the table, rather than the end, and the problem still occurs - when first inserted, a cell is 'invisible' until it goes offscreen and comes back on again. What could be causing this, and how can I force the cell to be drawn as soon as it is added to the table?*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're having problems because your updating the table without updating the data model backing it. Tables don't actually know how many rows they have nor what cells to display. They depend on the datasource and the delegate to tell them these things. Your design expects the table itself to track them.

`insertRowsAtIndexPaths:` is intended to be used for moving existing rows around a table, not for adding entirely new logical rows. When you insert an entirely new cell, the tableview looses track of how many rows it actually has.

Before you display a new row, the first thing you should do is update the values returned by:

```
– numberOfSectionsInTableView:
– tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:
```

... to reflect the addition of the new rows. This will allow the table to understand how big it is.

Then you need to update `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` to return the correct cell for the added row. Then you need to reload the table.

After you've done that, you should be able to scroll the tableview to the end and have the cell display properly.

The important thing to remember about tables is that they are dumb. The table itself holds no data, doesn't know how many sections and rows it has or what order the rows and sections come in. All the logic about data, sections, rows, cells and cell contents comes from the datasource and/or the delegate. When you want to change a table, you actually change the datasource and/or the delegate and then the table will reflect those changes automatically.

Edit:

Upon rereading the parent, I see that your putting the ***actual UITableViewCell objects*** in your data array and that you have one cell for each row.

***This is not how tableviews are supposed to work and this will not scale beyond a few dozen rows at most***.

Tableviews are intended to be an illusion that allows you display a lOGICAL table which has an arbitrary high number or rows. To that end, it only keeps enough UITableViewCell objects alive to cover the visually displayed area in the UI. With a default cell height of 44 pixels this means a tableview will never have more than 9 cell objects at a time.

Instead of eating memory holding cells that are not displayed, the tableview lets the delegate dequeue a cell that has scrolled off screen, repopulate it with the data of another LOGICAL row and then display it in a new position. This is done in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

You really need to start over here with your design.  Your data needs to be kept separate from the user interface objects. You don't want to have more cells alive at anyone time than absolutely necessary because your memory use will balloon and your response time will degrade. Your current problem is the result of this unusual design.

When you've done that, you can add the result row as outlined above.

Comment: The rows of my table are held in nested arrays. An outer NSMutableArray contains one inner NSMUtableArray for each section. Each section NSMutableArray contains the cells for that section. `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` returns the number of section arrays, and `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:' returns the number of cells in the relevant section array. `cellForRowAtIndexPath` uses the section and row numbers to locate the relevant row in my array structure, and returns that.

Comment: I'm not looking to have more than a few rows, let alone a few dozen. I'll look into a redesign, but I would like to have a short-term solution too.

Comment: Short-term, you have to make sure that datasource reflects the addition of the results cell when it returns the number of sections and rows. I would call `-[UITableView reload]` after you add the cell to the data array. That should cause the tableview to update itself with the proper number of sections and rows which will let it display itself properly. However, you are always going to have trouble with this design and it will always cause you a lot of extra work.

Answer (score 1):

Try to scroll with some time shift after cell update via NSTimer or performSelector:withDelay:. It can help but to fix all problems I think there need to do more work.

Comment: This helped previously, but now I am inserting rows to the middle of the table and it doesn't make a difference. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The glitches may be caused because a `UITableView` considers itself the owner of any `UITableViewCell` instances it is displaying, and reuses them as needed.  Part of that process is calling `prepareForReuse` on the cell.  Since you are keeping the cells in an array, you do not want them reused.  Try implementing an empty `prepareForReuse` in your `UITableViewCell` class.  Or just create cells dynamically in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` as apple recommends.

Answer (score 0):

I used what Skie suggested to avoid the problem in the following way:

Immediately after adding the row:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(scrollToDesiredArea:) withObject:newIndexPath afterDelay:0.4f];
```

This called the following:

```
-(void)scrollToDesiredArea:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
     UITableView *thisView = (UITableView*)self.view;
     [thisView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
}
```

The delay of 0.4s seems to be sufficient to avoid the glitching; any less and it still happens. It may have to be different on varying models of iPhone hardware, though - I only tested on emulator.

Comment: This worked reasonably well when I was just adding a cell to the end. However, now I am inserting a cell in the midst of the other cells it just fails to draw until it has been scrolled offscreen and back. The cells below it slide down, leaving an empty space through which I can see the grouped table background. Once this space is scrolled offscreen and back, it reveals itself as the cell that I added - and works perfectly from then on.